# How to create it test name with increment variable in Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am using Mocha and I would like to do something like this:

```
describe('My tests', () => {
let i
before(function () {
    i = 0
})
beforeEach(function () {
    i++
})

it('Test ' + i, function () {
    cy.log('inside first test')
})

it('Test ' + i, function () {
    cy.log('inside second test')
})
})
```

I get `Test undefined` as a test name, instead of `Test 1`, `Test2`. How can I achieve this in Mocha?

Comment: Think about *when* that code is running; the test names are defined when *registering* the actions, well before the `before[Each]` callbacks get called. Why not something like `[0, 1].forEach((i) => it(\`Test ${i}\`, () => { ... }))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to how hooks works, you can use an increment into the name like this.

```js
describe('My tests', () => {
    let i = 0
    it('Test ' + ++i, function () {
        console.log('inside first test')
    })
    
    it('Test ' + ++i, function () {
        console.log('inside second test')
    })
})
```

And you get the output:

```sh
  My tests        
inside first test 
    √ Test 1      
inside second test
    √ Test 2
```